# Generating random frames/projects using Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans-8

I was wondering if it is possible to generate random frames by storing them into an array or any methods you may suggest.

For instance, in my program I want to randomly access different frames by clicking a button and this is the code I have so far.

```
private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

// Generating a random number from 1 to 25 because I have 25 frames
int min = 1;
int max = 25;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + ,min;

// I have 25 files with the same name but they end with a different number (from 1 to 25)
String practice = "File" + randomNum

// Opening new frame
// Currently the code below does not work because I think "practice" is seen as a string and so the word is underlined in red
new practice().setVisible(true);

// Closing current frame
this.dipose();
}
```

I'm trying to store the frames/files/projects into an array, and then retrieve them using this code but it doesn't quite work.

Basically when the user is finished a question, he/she will click on the next button which will bring him/her to a new frame, but I want the frames to be randomly generated.

Comment: what really is FRAME?

Comment: Like a JFrame file

Comment: please add what real code you do have; the above is very incomplete and has compilation errors.  also, please specify what exactly is not "quite work[ing]"

Comment: Must understand Object programing, most basic Java concepts, I suggets on simple problems, from Hello Worlds etc. This "code" is a free set of dreams and wish, has nothing to real programming

Comment: @ryonts this fragment never aspire to be code, take it easy

Comment: Meliisa, if You have an idea of "array", why no array at all in Your ... in Your fragment

Comment: @Jacek Cz That's because I don't know how to store files into an array, currently I only know how to store integers and strings and I was **asking if it is possible** to store them in an array and retrieve them using another code. BTW the fragment of code You were talking about is the function for the button I was talking about earlier in my post about generating random files

Comment: do some exercises, store simple objects in a array, move from simple projects to more advanced. Get good book. Impossible to learn Java in SO comments